# Преобразование объекта ipaddres в str

Tags: python, ip, ip-address

У меня есть объект класса `ipaddress.ip_network(ip)` При помощи

```
range_ = ipaddress.ip_network(ip)
    for ip in range_:
        request(ip)
```

Я передаю в функцию элемент объекта. Каким методом можно его преобразовать в строку? Метода `__str__()` в этой библиотеке как понимаю нет

Comment: какая у вас версия Python? В Python 3.7 метод `ipaddress.ip_network.__str__()` есть

Comment: а в чем проблема? `request(ip)` --> `request(str(ip))` ?

Comment: @MaxU Сглупил, моя ошибка. Благодарю!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример для Python 3.7.6:

```
In [9]: from ipaddress import ip_network

In [10]: net = ip_network('192.0.2.0/24')

In [11]: net_str = str(net)

In [12]: net_str
Out[12]: '192.0.2.0/24'

In [13]: net.__str__()
Out[13]: '192.0.2.0/24'

In [14]: print(net)
192.0.2.0/24

In [15]: [str(sub) for sub in net.subnets()]
Out[15]: ['192.0.2.0/25', '192.0.2.128/25']
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [16]: [str(ip) for ip in net]
Out[16]:
['192.0.2.0',
 '192.0.2.1',
 '192.0.2.2',
 '192.0.2.3',
 '192.0.2.4',
 '192.0.2.5',
 '192.0.2.6',
 '192.0.2.7',
 '192.0.2.8',
 '192.0.2.9',
 '192.0.2.10',
 ...
```

Comment: Извините, я исправил вопрос, немного не так выразился